# как сделать навигацию по датам?

Tags: javascript, es5

Как сделать навигацию, чтобы выбирая дату из выпадающих списков поля ввода и кнопок (- + 1) получить день недели на любую произвольную дату?

```js
var selDay = document.getElementById('c_day');
var selDate = document.getElementById('c_date');
var selMonth = document.getElementById('c_month');
var inpYear = document.getElementById("c_year");
var selEra = document.getElementById("c_era");

var days = [
  "Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник",
  "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"
];

var months = [
  "января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля",
  "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа",
  "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"
];

var eras = [
  ["до н. э.", "-"],
  ["н. э.", "+"]
];

function getDaysMonth(d) {
  return 34 - new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 34).getDate();
}

getDaysMonth(new Date());

var date = new Date();

var daysMonth = getDaysMonth(date);

for (var i = 0; i < daysMonth; i++) {
  var opt = selDate.appendChild(new Option(i + 1, i));
  if (i + 1 === date.getDate()) opt.selected = true;
}

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) { // месяц
  var option = new Option(months[i], i);
  if (i === date.getMonth()) option.selected = true;
  selMonth.appendChild(option);
}

selDay.appendChild(new Option(days[date.getDay()])).selected = true; // день недели

inpYear.value = date.getFullYear();

inpYear.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var val = this.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  this.value = val.length > 6 ? val.slice(0, 6) : val;
});

for (var i = 0; i < eras.length; i++) {
  var opt = selEra.appendChild(new Option(eras[i][0], eras[i][1]));
  if (eras[i][0] === "н. э.") opt.selected = true;
}
```

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a,
select,
input,
textarea,
button {
  outline: none;
}

select,
input,
button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font: 20px serif;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input#c_year {
  width: 92px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block; // не все браузеры применяют свойство text-align: center; к полю ввода
}

.cont {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.cont_lr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.m_p {
  font: 12px/8px serif;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="c_day"></select><br>
  <span class="cont">
    <select id="c_date" class="cont"></select>
    <span class="cont_lr">
    <button id="munus_date" class="m_p">-</button>
    <button id="plus_date" class="m_p">+</button>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="cont">
    <select id="c_month" class="cont"></select>
    <span class="cont_lr">
    <button id="munus_month" class="m_p">-</button>
    <button id="plus_month" class="m_p">+</button>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="cont">
    <input type="text" id="c_year" class="cont"></select>
    <span class="cont_lr">
    <button id="munus_year" class="m_p">-</button>
    <button id="plus_year" class="m_p">+</button>
  </span>
  <span class="cont">
    <select id="c_era" class="cont"></select><br>
    <span class="cont_lr">
    <button id="munus_era" class="m_p">-</button>
    <button id="plus_era" class="m_p">+</button>
    </span>
  </span>
  <button id="today" style="display: none;">сегодня</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В конкретном случае Вам вероятно достаточно будет воспользоваться методом [toLocaleDateString()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwis0J6GooX-AhUXh_0HHQkQC_8QFnoECBoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fru%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FtoLocaleDateString&usg=AOvVaw0ZVIDuKMLjQvLnKsL0b2X-)  для вывода дня недели. Я воспользовался похожим [онлайн калькулятором](https://planetcalc.ru/79/) чтобы проверить дни.
Минус этого подхода, то что не понятно как вывести 1-ый год нашей эры и некоторые другие годы.

```js
// возвращает массив аргументов и дату с днем недели
function xDate(...args){
  const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric',  month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
  return [args, new Date(...args).toLocaleDateString('ru-ru', options)]
}

const dates = [
  xDate(),            // текущая дата
  xDate(-1 , 0 , 1),  // 1 января 2г
  xDate(0 , 0 , 1),   // 1 января 1900г
  xDate(1401, 0, 1),  // 1 января 1401 н.э.
  xDate(-1400, 0, 1), // 1 января 1401 до н.э.
]

for (const date of dates){
  console.log(date[0].join(', ').padEnd(15, ' '), date[1]);
}
```

Но вообще многие годы повторяются один в один (всего их 14):

- есть 7 високосных лет начинающихся сооответсвенно с (ПН, ВТ, СР, ЧТ, ПТ, СБ, ВС)
- есть 7 не високосных лет начинающихся сооответсвенно с (ПН, ВТ, СР, ЧТ, ПТ, СБ, ВС)

Таким образом зная какие годы похожи можно считать дни недели по одним годам получая их и для других.
Например не високосные годы начинающиеся с понедельника чередуются с разницей то в 11 то в 6 лет, закономерность есть но ее нужно увидеть тогда можно создать формулу для вычисления.

```
1906 + 11 = 1917; 1917 + 6  = 1923; 1923 + 11 = 1934
1934 + 11 = 1945 и т.д.
```

Приведу список похожих не високосных лет (то же самое и для других дней недели)

```
  понедельник, 1 января 1906г. 1917г. 1923г. 1934г. 1945г. ...
```

Вот список високосных лет можно заметить что между похожими разница 28 лет (я не проверял все, может есть исключения, но думаю там тоже есть закономерность)

```
понедельник, 1 января 1912г. 1940г. 1968г. 1996г.
вторник, 1 января 1924г. 1952г. 1980г. ...
```

И на последок, можно еще высчитывать сколько дней прошло до даты с начала года, и сколько лет было до даты (н.э) потом нужно будет посчитать сколько было високосных лет за этот период, и прибавить за каждый год по одному дню (29 февраля) далее имея число дней, можно поделить их нацело на 7 и таким образом получить день недели для пятницы будет 5 для понедельника 1 для воскресения 0.
Например для 31 марта 2023 года:

```
((90 + (2022 * 365) + 490) % 7 ) === 5 // пятница
```

- `90` дней с начала года (31 + 28 + 31 = 90)
- `2022` года разница между 1-м годом (2023 - 1 = 2022)
- `365` дней в каждом году (без 29 февраля — подсчитывается отдельно)
- `490` високосных лет (с 29 февраля)

Формула для определения високосный год или нет может быть такой:

```
function isLeapYear(year) {
  return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) 
}
```

Т.е. если год либо делится нацело на 4, но не на 100 или делится нацело на 400, тогда он високосный.

Я постарался дать достаточно данных чтобы Вы могли продолжить исследования самостоятельно. Теперь Вы знаете как вывести день недели, и как определить високосный год или нет. Так же что есть повторяющиеся годы которые чередуются с определенной закономерностью. Надеюсь, мой ответ окажется Вам полезным.

```js
let value = 1999
const [text, date, plus, minus] 
  = document.querySelectorAll('p, button')
plus.onclick = function(){
  text.textContent = value
  date.textContent =  new Date(value, 0, 1); 
}
minus.onclick = () => {
  text.textContent = '-'+`${value}`.padStart(6, '0')
  date.textContent =  new Date(text.textContent) 
}
```

```html
<p>1999</p><p></p>
<button>+</button>
<button>-</button>
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

*Как использовать выбранные значения*

Чтобы взять данные с селектов для числа месяца, месяца, и поля ввода, чтобы получить дату, нужно обратиться к каждому из этих элементов и взять value например так:

```
const month = selMonth.value //мы получим значение от 0 до 11 в зависимости от месяца.
const year = selMonth.value //мы получим значение от 0 до 11 в зависимости от месяца.

const date = selDate.value;   // [1-31]
const month = selMonth.value; // [0-11]
const year = +inpYear.value;  // у инпута лучше использовать type="number"
const era = selEra;  // ['-', '+']
```

Далее преобразовав нужным способом полученные значения мы можем их подствить в дату (за формулы не ручаюсь) например так:

```
const yearByEra = era === '+' ? year : parseInt(year) - 1
const padStartLenght = Math.abs(yearByEra) < 1000 && era === '-' ? 4 : 6

const yearPadded = era + `${yearByEra}`.padStart(padStartLenght, '0')
// расчет           +/-        15           0000 (ведущие нули)      => "+000015"

new Date(yearPadded, month, date)
```

Что касается дней то они должны быть в диапазоне от 1.

*События на кнопках*

В select мы должны присвоить по нажатию на кнопку либо предыдущую либо следующую опцию (по-значению) если эти опции есть. В input просто увеличить уменьшить значение.

Так как значения идут подрят мы можем менять их например так:

```
selDate.value = Number(selDate.value) + 1 // или - 1
selMonth.value = Number(selMonth.value) + 1 // или - 1
```

Для этого на кнопки мы должны добавить события по клику, обычно это делается так:

```
const munusDateBtn = document.getElementById('munus_date') // minus 
const plusDateBtn = document.getElementById('plus_date')

munusDateBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // обязательно проверяем что значение будет не ниже 0
    selDate.value = Number(selDate.value) - 1
}, false)

munusDateBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // обязательно проверяем что значение не будет больше 31
    selDate.value = Number(selDate.value) + 1
}, false)
```

```js
// 14 год ???
const month = 0
const date = 1
console.log(new Date (0014, month, date))
console.log(new Date ("0014", month, date))
//или в рассширенноом формате 
console.log(new Date (+000014, month, date))
console.log(new Date ("+000014", month, date))
```

Comment: для года есть три формата, обычный — когда любой год состоит из 4 цифр, используется для любого года от 1 до 9999 н.э. , getFullYear(0001), getFullYear(0010), getFullYear(0100),  getFullYear(1000), сокращенный, для 1900 — 1999, getFullYear(00) // 1900, getFullYear(01) // 1901, getFullYear(99) //1999, так же есть расширенный формат, для нулевого года и больше 9999, getFullYear(+000000) -1 // (нулевого года в григорианском календаре нету) 1г до н.э., getFullYear(+010000) // 10000г н.э., и также отрицательные значения для дат до н.э. getFullYear(-000001) -1 // 2г до н.э.

Comment: в выпадающем списке для эры, предусмотрены value с знаками - и +, только я не знаю как преобразовывать год введённый пользователем в инпут, к 4х значному, и 6ти значному формату используя знаки - и + из селекта для эры

Comment: (https://es5.javascript.ru/x15.9.html#x15.9.1.15.1)

Comment: Если я правильно понял то добавил снипет который приводит к 4х значному, и 6ти значному формату, в Вашем случае по тернарнику можно определить до или после. `padStart` добивает нулями до нужной длины

Comment: я просто недавно начала пытаться учить js, и не знаю как правильно сделать, чтобы взять данные с селектов для числа месяца, месяца, и поля ввода, чтобы получить дату, например new Date (2021, 6, 17) // 17 мая 2021 г,  new Date (0021, 7, 12) // 12 июня 21 г, new Date (0137, 8, 3) // 3 июля  137 г, new Date (+010054, 0, 19) // 19 января 10054 г, new Date ((+000000) -1, 2, 17) // 17 марта 1г до н.э,

Comment: new Date ((-000015) -1, 6, 17) // 17 мая 14 г до н.э, используя ещё и селект для эры, и как сделать чтобы при клике на кнопки + и - добавлялся/отнимался один соответственно число месяца, месяц или год...

Comment: Mon Jan 01 -1999 это равно понедельник, 1 января 1998 г до н.э.

Comment: @Белка не могу понять как создается 14 год нашей эры. Пробовал и "0014" и "000014" и "+000014" все равно 1914 год получается

Comment: 14 год это или в простом формате new Date (0014, month, date) или в рассширенноом формате new Date (+000014, month,  date), оба варианта дают 14 год нашей эры,

Comment: а года до нашей эры начинаются с 0 (подобно месяцу), new Date (+000000, month, date)  равно 1ому году до нашей эры, new Date (-000001, month, date) равно 2ому г до нашей эры, но 000000 со знаком плюс, а 000001 и далее со знаком минус

Comment: Добавил снизу снипет, там видно что ну никак 14 год не получается